# How to source remote scripts and assign variables remotely in rsh?

Tags: linux, bash, hp-ux, rsh

There is this problem that's been bothering me lately.

I'm trying to do the following using rsh or remsh (in HPUX):

```
#!/bin/sh
rsh myDNS"
  DIRECTORY=/tmp/foo1/foo2
  echo $DIRECTORY
"
```

When I try to run the above script, however, I get blank output for $DIRECTORY.  Consequently, when this issue is applied to the actual scripts I'm working on, bash claims that it could not find the specified script that I was trying to source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using ssh than using rsh or remsh.  rsh and remsh are very insecure - the transmit data in cleartext and are based on IP address authentication.

If you use double quotes like that, $DIRECTORY gets expanded on the initiating host, before rsh/remsh is started.

If you use single quotes (apostrophes) instead, $DIRECTORY should be expanded on the remote host.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The single quotations fixed everything.